# Navigating huge tab lists in Safari

Tags: safari, tabs

Sometimes it is said that huge tab lists are counter-productive and may actually decrease focus. Still it is often unavoidable when researching a wide subject. I really miss TreeStyleTabs from Firefox then.

Anyway - does Safari have any shortcuts to simplify navigating tabs? For instance, some sort of 'Back/Forward' between tabs, or 'bookmarking' some tab location? Sometimes it happens that the new tab is opened in the rightmost position, and it takes time to locate the previously browsed tab. The only alternative i know is built-in in Safari is `Show All Tabs` feature. But still it doesn't give the tab browsing history, so to speak.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Key commands for Next/Previous tab are...

Next =  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>  
Previous =  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>

There's a free/donationware Safari extension that can force some subtly different behaviour on tabs, might be worth a look - [LinkThing](http://canisbos.com/linkthing)

Comment: These shortcuts help! However, i was looking for something that would allow me to jump between tabs not necessarily next to each other (perhaps i've phrased myself unclearly). For instance, jump between 3rd and 25th tab, just because i've happened to click the 25th and now i want to go back to the 3rd quickly, without scrolling the tab list with the trackpad.

Comment: I'm afraid Safari doesn't have a direct to tab command, though iirc, Chrome does - Cmd/num [though not sure how it copes with more than 9]